# Ubuntu 14.04 resume error after suspend

Tags: suspend, toshiba-satellite

I recently updated my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 in my dual boot (windows 7) Toshiba Satellite Laptop. After the update, whenever the laptop suspends for sometime, it fails to resume. When I try to resume the laptop, by selecting Ubuntu from Grub loader, the login screen appears for a moment goes black and continues this back and forth for a couple of times and eventually goes back to "Suspend". I have to hard boot the system to get into Ubuntu. Below I have attached first few lines of the crash report:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: This occured during a previous hibernate and prevented it from resuming properly.
Architecture: i386
Date: Wed Apr 30 10:57:56 2014
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ExecutableTimestamp: 1397576330
Failure: hibernate/resume
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.4
Package: linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ProcCwd: /
ProcEnviron:
 TERM=linux
 PATH=(custom, no user)
.....
```

Comment: This is also a persistent problem for me

Comment: @labnut, try switch to tty1 Ctrl+Alt+F1, then `sudo pm-hibernate", boot again, when it's ready see if you can switch back to GUI tty7 Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: aaarah!  error message says "Failure: hibernate/resume"  Title of this question implies this is a Suspend error.  Suspend and hibernate are two totally different things..  Different issues, different root causes.  Probably best to create accurate titles.  (In my case I have a suspend issue, not a hibernate issue... This posting pops to the top of the google search and is not at all related to suspend failures.)

Answer (score 2):

Solution worked for me (copied from my personal manuals without modification).
I've got Lenovo T530 with Ubuntu 14.04; mainline kernel 3.14.9; nvidia-331-updates package installed (331.38-0ubuntu7).

=> suspend/resume works for me quite well.
=> I was solving also problem with resume after hibernation, and the solution: eject SD card from the laptop! :-|

My comments that worked for me (some months ago):

```
suspendResume_WORKING() {
# WIFI solution
# 1.) sudo vi /etc/pm/config.d/modules
# 2.) Replace SUSPEND_MODULES with this line:
#         SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES uhci_hd button ehci_hd iwlwifi"

# SD card solution:
# 3.) Copy file from https://github.com/wschaub/T530-    settings/blob/master/pm/sleep.d/unmount_sdcard
#     to /etc/pm/sleep.d/unmount_sdcard
# 4.) chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/unmount_sdcard

# ACPI solution:
# 5.) Replace lines in /etc/default/grub
#     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noquiet nosplash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_sleep=s4_nohwsig loop.max_part=63 loop.max_loop=64"
#     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


# X.) sudo update-initramfs -u
# X+1.) sync; sudo reboot

}
```

Comment: I had the same problem on my Thinkpad T530 too.
While loading, 

`Enter-> F1-> Config -> Display -> Intel video adapter`
instead of `Discrete video adapter` solved problem for me.

Comment: :thumbs_up: ACPI solution helped me with my Lenovo z50-70 laptop — it didn't wake up after suspend. Now everything seems to be ok!

Comment: I downvoted because there is no info on how to actually apply this fix. Where is function `suspendResume_WORKING()`? Why does this solution work? What are you actually doing when you copy/paste this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I managed to get hibernate to work again by changing the graphics card driver. Under additional drivers I have the following:

1. NVIDIA binary driver 331.113 - causes the error above
2. NVIDIA legacy binary driver 304.125 - hibernate works with this
3. Nouveau display driver -  - hibernate works with this, but I would get other errors unrelated to hibernate

Below is a snippet of my crash log.

ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: This occured during a previous hibernate and prevented it from resuming properly.
Architecture: amd64
Date: Mon Jan  5 09:20:38 2015
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ExecutableTimestamp: 1414700591
Failure: hibernate/resume
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.4
Package: linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic 3.13.0-43.72

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm about a year late in responding but I've been fighting this problem for a while and finally found a solution that works for me.

It came from here:
http://geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/#more-377

First, use

```
ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci
```

There should be a file with 0000:00:xx.x format. Take note of it.

Then modify /etc/rc.local, adding this one line after the shebang (the first line):

```
echo -n 0000:00:xx.x | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
```

Filling in the xx.x with whatever your file was called. For me it was 0000:00:1d.0

It should work on reboot, or you can enter that line into the terminal for immediate fix.

Good luck to anyone who needs it. I know I did

Comment: Why does this work? What does it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Linux kernel of at least 4.2 - 4.4. Actually, the failure of resume can mean that the screen is dark but the system can be on; successfully typing login can result in successful login and bright display; however, not always. 
You can solve the case by upgrade to Linux Kernel 4.6. Please, see a similar case in Lenovo Thinkpad B51 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1560202), but the case is universal to all Linux 4.2-4.4 i.e. also your system. 
It is easy and smooth to upgrade luckily to Linux kernel 4.6 from 4.4, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786497/25388). It can also possible so from 4.2. However, I would do a fresh installation of 16.04 now and upgrade there from 4.4 to 4.6.

Ubuntu: 14.04 and 16.04
Linux kenel: 4.2 - 4.4
Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad B51, Lenovo Thinkpad G50-30, Macbook Air 2013-mid, ...