# How to Install Linux Kernel 4.6 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kernel, macbook

I do but get dependency errors which I do not understand

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic.
(Reading database ... 412868 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic:
 linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic depends on linux-headers-4.6.0-040600; however:
  Package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic
```

I do `masi@masi:~$ sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600.
(Reading database ... 418610 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.6.0-040600 (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.6.0-040600 (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
Will not try to make an initrd.
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
Setting up linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic (4.6.0-040600.201606100558) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic

Good news! Module version  for wl.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 4.6.0-040600-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.6.0-040600-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

where there are some errors/warnings

- `: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
  Will not try to make an initrd.
  rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
  Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
  DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.`
- Should I overwrite with force? `Good news! Module version  for wl.ko
  exactly matches what is already found in kernel 4.6.0-040600-generic.
  DKMS will not replace this module.
  You may override by specifying --force.`

Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4, but wanted 4.6

Comment: Why do you install only this headers package. There are other packages to install.

Comment: Why do you need the 4.6 kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6 Because of suspend/resume problem with my hardware, it is solved in Linux kernel 4.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to install only one package of **three** required.

Download these packages  to your Home folder:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb

You can do it using `wget` or using a browser.

Then run `sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`

Comment: They have dependencies. If you do it in a correct order, you can do it one by one. But installing all 3 is much easier.

Comment: BTW The actual kernel is only `linux-image` package.

Comment: You see it in the error message. The last package depends on the first. There are no other restrictions. You can also see the dependencies in `debian/control` file in the package itself.

Comment: It says that the `linux-headers...-all.deb` can't be installed without `linux-headers-generic...deb`, does not it?

Comment: Ooops! It is vice versa.

Comment: The `generic` can't be installed without `all`.

Comment: It does not matter to replace it or not.

Comment: Everything looks OK. The kernel is installed.

Comment: You might need the linux-image-extra-4.6... package for some drivers also.

Comment: There is no `extra` for kernel 4.6.

Answer (score 3):

Here

**64Bit:**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**32Bit**:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: just use `uname -r` to check your kernel version. Sorry I don't fully understand your question