# Why Ubuntu 16.04 Setups Linux Kernel 4.4 in Linux kernel 4.6 Installation?

Tags: apt, kernel, 16.04

I installed Linux kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786497/25388).
After 17 days of use, I started to get System crashes at the startup, which logs I sent to developers. 
I do where same output also for `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for masi: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
....
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,327 B]
Fetched 1,861 kB in 2s (707 kB/s)                                           
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I do but it starts to setup Linux 4.4 there too about which I am not sure

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-tools-4.4.0-28 (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... 

Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file. Would you like /boot/grub/menu.lst generated for you? (y/N) y
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

Setting up linux-tools-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.28.30) ...
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.28.30) ...
Setting up linux-tools-virtual (4.4.0.28.30) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.4.0.28.30) ...
Setting up linux-generic-lts-utopic (4.4.0.28.30) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
```

Output of `uname -r` is `4.6.0-040600-generic`.

Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl
Reason for 4.6 Linux kernel: lid-suspend problem in 4.4, fixed much in 4.6

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 does not have kernel 4.6. Did you install it manually? Why?

Comment: Lid-suspend problem in 4.4. Fixed in 4.6.

Comment: What is the output of this command? `uname -r`

Comment: I believe you already tried to install a 4.6 kernel using instructions from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/786491/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-6-in-ubuntu-16-04/786497

Comment: @ColinIanKing Of course, its mine thread linked here for showing you how I did it originally.